# Can the REPL in the vscode debug window be set to multiline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

When testing in the vs code debug window REPL, I notice that there appears to be only one line. This makes it harder to work with longer expressions. Is there any way to make it multiline or word wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to expand the `repl` to however many lines you need.

And you can backspace to clear those extra lines.

Also just pasting in multi-lines expands the `repl` automatically.

[image: expand repl]

Comment: Not sure If I'm doing something wrong , but shift + enter doesn't appear to do anything. I'm working in a chromebook on linux

Comment: wait, it works , but only while you are running the program.